# Giver deployment issues

Tags: solidity, everscale

my software started saying my giver is not deployed, but it is deployed, obviously.

I guess this is about endpoints. Could you please help me wrap my head around what's to be fixed? THx a lot!

everdev contract deploy FarmingCalculator.abi.json -n dev -s dev_giver -v 250000000 -d _randomNonce:13

Configuration

Network: dev (eri01.net.everos.dev, rbx01.net.everos.dev, gra01.net.everos.dev)
Signer:  dev_giver (public 191fb7466066419bb44da39d58c2c1161255da87453b0447dc2500a4927b57db)

Address:   0:9781a951a6c8c8961e7f5467e308c6983189c3746557cf5cc5739d5a2dbc39a2 (calculated from TVC and signer public)
Error: Giver 0:5236a17bd571ad5cf8acda004158e94f97d61833c3a11484e23dd9e97374f9f7 has no code deployed."

Answer (score 0):

try this:

everdev network credentials dev --project ""Project Id""

(Don't forget to install the latest everdev version and you need to be athorized)